# override payment/methods.phtml in custom extension

Tags: module, template, overrides, magento-1, payment-methods

I am creating custom extension in my magento site. In this extension i need to add my own code while selecting `Bank Transfer Payment` method.

So basically I need to override `payment/methods.phtml`.

**Magento File Full Path :** app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

I have created same file in my custom directory.

**My custom module full path:**

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/market/methods.phtml

- market is my module directory name

**My xml path resides at :**

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/my_market.xml

**Code wriitten in xml to override:**

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
         <reference name="checkout.onepage.paymentmethods">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>market/methods.phtml</template>
           </action>            
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

I think reference name is wrong. Please someone help which reference name should I use to override `payment/methods.phtml`. :)

Comment: Did you add layout updates from my_market.xml to your module config.xml?

Comment: Yes. I have successfully overridden some other templates from the front side like  account,sidebar,payment review etc. which are from same xml file.

Comment: I think it a bad idea to change the template to add a custom payment method. Do you try to add it by JavaScript? I think I can try to implement some example in free time.

Comment: I want to override because I want to put my own method on the click  of bank transfer checkout checkbox  `<input type="radio" class="radio" onclick="payment.switchMethod('banktransfer')" title="Bank Transfer Payment" name="payment[method]" value="banktransfer" id="p_method_banktransfer">`

Comment: Yes. I ll use jquery if i dont find solution of the above issue. payment.phtml has successfully overridden so i think payment/mehods.phtml should also override with some basic xml settings

Comment: I think the Js approach is a better solution then overriding template. It is more flexible.  In this case may be used Prototype. There is just investigate how to work with the checkout js object, understand which interface it provide to use.

Answer (score 1):

You SHould use below code to override methods.phtml

```
<checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="codverify/methods.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```